# Django - Autocomplete Search Throws Error For Logged Out Users?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I’m making some updates to the autocomplete portion of the search functionality in my application and for some reason i’m getting an error for logged out users that says `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x1088a5e20>>.`

This is only happening for logged out users. When users are logged in the autocomplete works as built so I know I’m missing something but I just don’t know what.

What needs to get changed to fix this issue?

I’m building a gaming application where users have access to play certain games based on their rank in our application. So when a user is logged in I’d like the autocomplete functionality to reflect the games they have unlocked.
So let’s say if a user has a `rank` of `100` then all the games with a `game_rank` of 100 and below will be displayed.
For logged out users I would like all games to be shown.

Made some notes in my `views.py` code from what I tested and added the JavaScript to the search functionality just in case.

Below is my code.

Any help is gladly appreciated!

All My Best!

**models.py**

```
class Game_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    game_rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    game_image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='game_covers', null=True, blank=True)


class User_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/profile_pics/default.png', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

**views.py**

```
def search_results_view(request):
    if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest': 
        res = None
        game = request.POST.get('game')
        print(game)

        ## This works for both logged in and logged out users but inlcudes all games. Would like to have this for logged out users. Commenting this out to test below. 
        # qs = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game).order_by('game_title')[:4]

        ## This only works for when users are logged in. 
        user_profile_game_obj = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
        user_profile_rank = int(user_profile_game_obj.rank)
        qs = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game, game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank).order_by('game_title')[:4]

        if len(qs) > 0 and len(game) > 0:
            data = []
            for pos in qs:
                item ={
                    'pk': pos.pk,
                    'name': pos.game_title,
                    'game_provider': pos.game_provider,
                    'image': str(pos.game_image.url),
                    'url': reverse('detail', args=[pos.pk]),
                }
                data.append(item)
            res = data
        else:
            res = 'No games found...'

        return JsonResponse({'data': res})
    return JsonResponse({})
```

**custom.js**

```
// Live Search Functionalty 
$(function () {
    const url = window.location.href
    const searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");
    const searchInput = document.getElementById("search_input_field");
    const resultsBox = document.getElementById("search-results");
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value

    const sendSearchData = (game) =>{
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/games/',

            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
                'game' : game,
            },
            success: (res)=> {
                console.log(res.data)
                const data = res.data
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    resultsBox.innerHTML = `<div class="search_heading"><h1>Recommended Games</h1></div>`
                    data.forEach(game=> {
                        resultsBox.innerHTML += `                    
                            <a href="${game.url}" class="item" >                          
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="search-cover-container">
                                        <img src="${game.image}" class="game-img">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="search-title-container">
                                        <p>${game.name}</p>
                                        <span class="publisher_title">${game.game_provider}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="search-icon-container">
                                        <i class="material-icons">trending_up</i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        `
                    })
                } else {
                   if (searchInput.value.length > 0) {
                    resultsBox.innerHTML = `<h2>${data}</h2>`
                   } else {
                    resultsBox.classList.add('not_visible')
                   }
                }
            },
            error: (err)=> {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }

    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', e=> {
        sendSearchData(e.target.value)
    })

});
```

**base.html**

```
            <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="search-form" action="{% url 'search_results' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="search_input_field" type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" class="form-control gs-search-bar" placeholder="Search Games..." value="">
                    <div id="search-results" class="results-container not_visible"></div>
                    <span class="search-clear">x</span>
                    <button id="search-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search-button" disabled>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
                        </span> 
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the query you're showing, logged out users should not even be able to navigate to this view. I'd decorate the view with [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

The problem you're seeing is on this line:

```py
user_profile_game_obj = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

When a user isn't logged in, `request.user` is an `AnonymousUser` instance, which doesn't have an ID. When that query is made, the underlying framework grabs the ID of the passed instance, which in this case isn't resolvable. You can't associate an `AnonymousUser` with a record, they don't have an identifier, and cannot be used in queries.

Alternatively, you can change the behavior of the view by using [`user.is_authenticated()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

---

**Edit:** Given the requirements, I'd refactor your view to the following.

```py
from http import HTTPStatus


def search_results_view(request):
    if not request.headers.get("x-requested-with") == "XMLHttpRequest":
        # Give an error response when something unexpected happens
        return JsonResponse(
            {"error": "Invalid request"}, status_code=HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        )

    # Create the primary queryset, then additionally filter it if the user is logged in
    game = request.POST.get("game")
    games = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game).order_by("game_title")
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_info = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
        games.filter(game_rank__lte=user_info.rank)

    # Return the JSON response with a list comprehension, limiting the queryset to 4 items
    return JsonResponse(
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "pk": game.pk,
                    "name": game.game_title,
                    "game_provider": game.game_provider,
                    "image": game.game_image.url,
                    "url": reverse("detail", args=[game.pk]),
                }
                for game in games.limit(4)
            ]
        }
    )
```

With that, I would refactor your frontend code to handle receiving an empty response and an error response.

**Note:** There's a lot more I would do here.

- You aren't actually using Django's templating system, so you'd likely be much better served by writing a [DRF application](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).
- There are issues with your naming conventions. According to PEP8 guidelines, [class names should be in `UpperCamelCase`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names), so your models should be `GameInfo` and `UserInfo`.
- I would use a `ListView` class for this instead of a method view, customizing it to return a `JsonResponse`. Not totally necessary, but why do extra work when `ListView` is designed for exactly this purpose

I could go on and probably add 3-4 more things, but I'm pretty opinionated so I won't.

Comment: So if I add ``@login_required`` I then get a message that says``Undefined`` where the autocomplete displays for logged out users when they do a search. What would you suggest to display all the games for logged out users?

Comment: My focus is front end development so I'm doing the workload that other people do on dev teams I'm on. I'll make some of the updates you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: If you're interested this is the tutorial I followed for the needs of the application I'm building: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIcCi2SG1CU

Comment: If you want to stick with Django and not move to DRF, I'd actually recommend you pick up `HTMX` and possibly `Alpine.js`. That way you can actually use the power of Django's templating engine, while mixing in AJAX requests and Alpine components while reducing the amount of boilerplate JS you have to write. Here's a good read: https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/htmx-alpine/

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to ask, do you have any good resources for DRF? I have DRF with swagger in the app I'm building and I followed William Vincent's book called Django for APIs. It's pretty basic to get a project quick up and rolling but doesn't go into any complex things.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by [@Sam Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4881095/sam-morgan), `request.user` is an `AnonymousUser`.  Adding `@login_required` won't help with that, but using the `user.is_authenticated()` should work:

```py
def search_results_view(request):
    if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest': 
        res = None
        game = request.POST.get('game')
        print(game)

        ## This works for both logged in and logged out users but inlcudes all games. Would like to have this for logged out users. Commenting this out to test below. 
        # qs = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game).order_by('game_title')[:4]

        ## This only works for when users are logged in. 
        if request.user.is_authenticated: 
            user_profile_game_obj = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
            user_profile_rank = int(user_profile_game_obj.rank)
            qs = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game, game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank).order_by('game_title')[:4]

        else:
            qs = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game).order_by('game_title')[:4]

        if len(qs) > 0 and len(game) > 0:
            data = []
            for pos in qs:
                item ={
                    'pk': pos.pk,
                    'name': pos.game_title,
                    'game_provider': pos.game_provider,
                    'image': str(pos.game_image.url),
                    'url': reverse('detail', args=[pos.pk]),
                }
                data.append(item)
            res = data
        else:
            res = 'No games found...'

        return JsonResponse({'data': res})
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Comment: That works. Too Early in the morning. Slowly waking up. You guys are ninjas! Thanks!